# Relative path link ignores proxy nginx

Tags: nginx, proxypass

Gitlab server running pages at https://pages.example.com
Gitlab pages correctly setup to serve one page at https://example.com/ instead of https://user.pages.example.com
Because inabilty to cname from https://user.pages.example.com/ to https://example.com with google domains, I have an nginx reverse proxy setup as such:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://user.pages.example.com;
    }

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Works fine when going to https://example.com (shows https://example.com rather than https://user.pages.example.com)
Link from index.html on that page goes to `./folder/` then url switches to https://user.pages.example.com/folder/ (bad)
Should go to https://example.com/folder/

I am stumped as to how to fix.

Comment: You need to fix the root URL in your Gitlab.

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry.

Comment: GitLab should have a root URL setting, where you specify what is the root URL of Gitlab. In your case, it should be set to `https://example.com` instead of `https://user.pages.example.com`

Comment: I can't do that since I want the website served at `https://example.com` not the gitlab ui.

Comment: You should change similar setting for Gitlab Pages then.

Comment: Again, I'm afraid I don't follow what you mean.

Comment: The URLs in the pages are generated by Gitlab Pages. This means, you need to modify its settings so that it generates correct URLs in HTML code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113539/discussion-between-thechubbypanda-and-tero-kilkanen).